# How can I make the Songs LaTeX package's index order be in Swedish?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I'm making a song book in LaTeX, using the [Songs package](http://songs.sourceforge.net/songsdoc/songs.html), and have been trying to find a way to get the index ordered according to Swedish alphabetical ordering (i.e. A-Z, then ÅÄÖ). The Songs package (or maybe LaTeX in general?) treats Å and Ä as simply A:s, and Ö as an O.

I build the index using the command

```
\newindex{mainindex}{register}
```

at the beginning of the book, before the actual songs, and

```
\showindex{Register}{mainindex}
```

at the end of the book.